# Can't select text with mouse in Word / Office 2007

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word

I'm having a very weird problem here for the last few months.  In Word, and in fact all programs from the Office 2007 suite, I can't drag the mouse pointer to select text.

I can click at a point in the text and the cursor moves correctly to that point.  If I double click, the word under the cursor is selected, and triple clicking selects the whole line.  However if I hold the mouse button down and drag the mouse, no text is selected.

Occasionally the problem disappears and everything works fine, but it then reappears a few minutes later.  Text selection with the mouse works everywhere else (Firefox, PuTTY, OpenOffice), just not in Office.

The only addins are Google Desktop Office Addin, and Person Name ().

For info it is Office 2007 SP3, running on Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and just replaced the battery on my wireless mouse. Now it appears to work (but like you, it would work intermittently before).

Answer (score 0):

I tried opening Word in Safe mode (Hold Ctrl key when double clicking Word icon) If the mouse/touchpad works okay, then it's probably not a mouse or touchpad issue, but another program which is affecting Word. Try Ctrl+Alt+Del, select Task Manager, and under the 'start up' tab, disable various start up programs one by one. Shut down and restart the computer each time and try Word again until you find the culprit.  In my case, it was Microsoft Edge, which appeared after a Windows 10 update.  Since then, I've not had issues with this previously frequent error. Hope this helps somebody else!

Answer (score -1):

Try to open MS Word "Run as administrator". This is not fix but work in some cases. I Think the problem is whit user's access level restricts